Why writeRaster() function has error : external pointer is not valid when I export ebird raster data?
I want to export the ebird relative abundance raster as a TIFF file, but I encountered this Error: external pointer is not valid
Here is my code:
library(terra)
library(ebirdst)

set_ebirdst_access_key("XXXXXXXXXXXX")
# download data, Anas acuta
ebirdst_download_status(species = "Anas acuta")

# load relative abundance raster 
abd <- load_raster("Anas acuta", resolution = "27km",product = "abundance",
                   period = "full-year"
                   )

writeRaster(abd, filename = "ebrid_test.tif")

I just want to save the species full-year relative abundance raster from ebird.

When you ebirdst_download_status(species = "Anas acuta"), were 28 files downloaded? I couldn't reproduce the error with following packages[1] ebirdst_3.2022.4    sf_1.0-17           rnaturalearth_1.0.1
[4] fields_15.2         viridisLite_0.4.2   spam_2.10-0
[7] terra_1.7-81        sp_2.1-4 list.files()[7] "ebird_anas_acuta_78828706_sof.tif", perhaps try with new session.

Probably not a big deal in this case, but it's not best practice to include your personal access key (set_ebirdst_access_key("q1kum0g8p0k")) in publicly posted code. (This does make it easier for others to reproduce your problem without having their own eBird access token, but would also make it possible for them to abuse the access that you're responsible for ...)

I appreciate your reminder lol

This appears to be related to your setup. Perhaps a faulty installation of "terra". I suggest reinstalling "terra" in a clean entirely empty session, using RGui or command-line (do not use R-Studio). When providing an example, you should also start in a clean session and show all output where it occurs (including the printed version number of "terra").
Also note that using writeRaster is a rather inefficient way to copy a file, see below for a better solution.
I get
library(ebirdst)
set_ebirdst_access_key("q1kum0g8p0k")
ebirdst_download_status(species = "Anas acuta")
abd <- load_raster("Anas acuta", resolution = "27km",product = "abundance", period = "full-year")
abd
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 626, 1502, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 26665.26, 26665.28  (x, y)
#extent      : -20015109, 20036111, -6684911, 10007555  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs 
#source      : norpin_abundance_full-year_mean_27km_2022.tif 
#name        : full_year 
#min value   :    0.0000 
#max value   :  108.6695 

And
x <- terra::writeRaster(abd, filename = "ebrid_test.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 626, 1502, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 26665.26, 26665.28  (x, y)
#extent      : -20015109, 20036111, -6684911, 10007555  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs 
#source      : ebrid_test.tif 
#name        : full_year 
#min value   :    0.0000 
#max value   :  108.6695 


library(terra)
#terra 1.7.78

Instead of using terra::writeRaster you can use file.copy
terra::sources(abd) |> file.copy("ebird_test_2.tif", overwrite = FALSE)


Thank you for your response, my problem has been resolved!
